# When I add new style with jQuery will it overwrite css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, append

Lets say I have this jQuery code

```
$('head').append('<style>body, html { margin: 0!important; }.. even more ...</style>');
```

Will this overwrite the current css (note the `!important`)
I've tested it in my browser and it is working as expected and overwriting the current css.

What I basically want is to add some css without a .css file.

Comment: .append() has absolutely nothing to do with this. Neither does javascript or jquery really. If you add a new style or stylesheet after an existing style or stylesheet, it overwrites any styles set before it as long as the new styles have a higher specificity.

Comment: Am I missing something, or did you answer the question in the question itself?

Comment: @David I am not sure if this is normal behaviour and if this will be always the case.

Comment: @KevinB thanks. All what I wanted to know. It's sad how freely people give down votes on stackoverflow just because of newbie questions. I did the research and could not find anything. It's not like it is something very obvious for a newbie

Comment: I don't think the fact that his is a newbie question is why you received downvotes. that is a very common miss-understanding.

Comment: Ok, why then? Sorry if it's obvious...

Comment: You seem to answer the question yourself. "When i do x, y happens. Will y happen when i do x?" You've already proven that.

Comment: Ok, but I just wanted to make sure if this is normal behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Since you applied a direct style tag, it will overwrite any css.  !important always writes over any class, and is generally considered bad practice.  why not add a class?

Comment: @yoshi: It would probably be easier to keep the styling static and modify the markup dynamically.  For example, you can have two sets of styles targeting elements under specific `body#id`s and then just change the `id` of the `body` with JavaScript.  (That's just one example, you can more explicitly target your styling/markup changes more effectively of course.)

Comment: @David Yes I know that. But this is a rare case where I think I have to do it like this.

Comment: @yoshi if it absolutely has to be dynamic, I would do what you did I suppose, but I would at least store any variables in an array maybe to be able to change them later